# ...otherProps in func React with TypeScript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, intrinsicattributes

I have this part of code:

```
<InputComponent
id="email"
name={formik.values.email}
type="text"
formik={formik}
className="signInInput"
disabled/>
```

And part with **disabled** and **className** have a mistake:
*Property "disabled" doesn't exist in type "IntrinsicAttributes & { id: string; name: string; type: string; formik: any; className: string;}"*

**InputComponent**  looks like:

```
interface ForProps{ 
    id: string, 
    name: string, 
    type: string, 
    formik: any,
    otherProps?: React.HTMLAttributes<HTMLInputElement>}

export default function InputComponent({id, name, type, formik, ..otherProps}: 
ForProps) {
    return(
        <TextField
        id={id}
        type={type}
        value={formik.values[name]}
        onChange={formik.handleChange}
        onBlur={formik.handleBlur}
        error={formik.touched[name] && !!formik.errors[name]}
        {..otherProps}/>
    )
}
```

How can I involve otherProps in this component with TS and without mistakes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Solution moved](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/309552/997587) from [@AlinaVoytovich](https://stackoverflow.com/users/20041936/alina-voytovich)'s question post.

> You should initialized your otherPeops in this way(other attributes will stick to your ..otherProps if you write: suggestSomeAttribute **?:** someType):
>
> ```
> interface ForProps{ 
>     id: string, 
>     name: string, 
>     type: string, 
>     formik: any,
>     className?: string,
>     disabled?: boolean}
>
> export default function InputComponent({id, name, type, formik, ...otherProps}: ForProps)
> ```